# Using Field calculator Logic in Python Script

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

I want to implement the calculation logic of field calculator in a custom Python script. Basically use QGIS inbuilt functions such as `num_point`, `$area`, `perimeter` etc function in my plugin for creating one polygon and then full vector layer. I need some way to use this `num_points($geometry)` in my Python script directly.

Input

```
num_point_geom = num_points(geometry)
print("num_point_geom ->:",num_point_geom)
```

Output

```
NameError: name 'num_points' is not defined
```

I have already researched QGIS cookbook and all other websites related to QGIS and field calculator but no luck.

Can anyone help me to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are expression functions and only used in the Field Calculator. You can
check the [QgsGeometry documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/latest/core/QgsGeometry.html) to find their equivalent.

For example; (test in QGIS Python Editor)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feature = next(layer.getFeatures())
geom = feature.geometry()

print(f"Area: {geom.area()}") # area in 2D
print(f"Perimeter: {geom.length()}") # perimeter in 2D

num_points = len(list(geom.vertices()))
print(f"Points count: {num_points}")
```

You may not find the equivalent of some expressions. You need to code yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response, I apply the above logic in my code but the value is still mismatched with the calculator value,
For Example
With QGIS calculator perform below operation
num_points($geomatry) 
it gives me 67

With above code
num_points = len(list(geom.vertices()))
print(f"Points count: {num_points}")

It gives me 5
Here I attached one screenshot of my QGIS, please help me to solve it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fc7jmJ0rD547sk6okQu8ZDXDp3xvNW2F/view?usp=sharing